# Ubuntu Network Manager and VLAN

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, vlan

On Ubuntu I set up a VLAN on eth5 as eth5.1451. I want to configure it using network manager(nm-applet), but network manager does not see the newly created VLAN? Is there a way to make NM recognize it?

Answer (score 1):

Is eth5 a physical interface? From memory NetworkManagerDispatcher is the issue, as it won't see virtual interfaces created from physical network interfaces.

What does the output of "nm-tool" and "NetworkManager --no-daemon" produce?